# Zest Eclipse Maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, zest

I am trying to download Zest in Eclipse Juno but unfortunately, I could not manage to do so. What I need is:

```
org.eclipse.zest
```

I could not find the Maven dependency for Zest and do not know how to get that installed. does anyone know how to get Zest installed in Eclipse Juno and how I can do with this with Maven. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a hold of the source code, and `mvn install` it, which would make it available to eclipse by using your local repository. Alternatively, if you have your own maven server (e.g. a nexus installation) you could `mvn deploy` it or directly upload the artifact.

Comment: I have Maven. What I cant understand is why do I need to install nexus or have a repository in order to get Zest installed?

Comment: When you add a dependency in your pom, maven goes and tries to fetch it from your local repository. Failing that, it goes to your remote repository, i.e. maven central by default. Now, since neither your local nor your remote repo have it, you either use `mvn install` to install the src code of Zest into your local repo, or you use your own remote repo (which proxies over to maven central) and drop zest in there